# Stop Yosemite menu bar redraw

Tags: macos, menu-bar

The menu bar seems to redraw itself each time I switch from monitor to other. [here's a short video](http://cl.ly/1X0c3o3s3v0w) of this happening. [This guy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152038/prevent-redraw-of-menu-bar-icons-yosemite) seems to have the same problem.

I tried using guest account without any 3rd part applications but the same problem persists.

Any help troubleshooting is welcome.