# Icons on menu bar redraw at each monitor change

Tags: display, high-sierra, icon, menu-bar, bug

I have an issue with my setup that drives me nuts and is more and more annoying.

I have a 4 displays setup and each time I change of monitor most of the icons in the menu redraw and introduce lag before activation of the clicked window.
[image]

I have done some research and found [this old post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152038/prevent-redraw-of-menu-bar-icons-yosemite), it looks like it was a known bug of Yosemite which has been resolved since...

Has anyone the same issue ?

Do you have some workarounds to get rid of it ?

Currently, I tried everything, and only the option which "resolves" the problem is disabling "displays have different spaces" (in this case, there is only one menu bar on the main display). However, this in not an option for me because I use the awesome chunkwm which requires this option to be enabled.

Any clue ?

Thanks

--
EDIT1: Thx for the suggestions.

Running in safe mode doesn't seems to have the issue, however the display performance is so terrible that I don't know if this is a good test case for that issue.

Switching the theme to white didn't help, the redraw is still here.

I use Bartender but did some tests in a new session without any programs running except iStats menu to monitor what append and still have the problem.

It looks like that the bug arises only when I move the mouse from the MBP display to an external monitor and when the GPU memory reach around 50% usage. It looks like the more the GPU uses memory, the more the bug is present and painful.

I observed that GPU memory usage increases a lot over time and with the number of displays connected. But disconnecting/connecting an external display frees lot of memory.

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in safe mode (⇧-boot)? Does this only occur with dark status bar? Do you run any menu bar management apps e.g. Bartender, or otherwise have you tried quitting various menu bar apps and seeing if the problem disappears?

Comment: I have the same issue, while it's annoying it's really only lasts 1-3 seconds, so it doesn't bother me too much

Comment: Thansk a lot for your suggestions, I edited my original answer with some answers. @RushilSrivastava the main problem is not the redraw which is annoying but the lag that is introduced each time I change on display. I loose clicks and need to click often two times or wait before being able to switch tabs for example in the browser. That's really annoying in the long term.